# Increase Provisioned IOPS in RDS leads to downtime?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, provisioned-iops

We have an `m4.2x large` RDS Postgres instance, with 300 GB storage and 1000 Provisioned IOPS.

We want to increase the PIOPS to 2000, will there be a downtime involved? 
If the performance will be downgraded, is there a measure by how much?

I could not find any relevant documentation talking about effects of increasing PIOPS on the instance while the change is taking place.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There will be no downtime according to Amazon. Reference below.

IOPS:
The new Provisioned IOPS (I/O operations per second) value for the RDS instance. **Changing this setting does not result in an outage** and the change is applied during the next maintenance window unless the ApplyImmediately parameter is set to true for this request.

Default: Uses existing setting

Constraints: Value supplied must be at least 10% greater than the current value. Values that are not at least 10% greater than the existing value are rounded up so that they are 10% greater than the current value. If you are migrating from Provisioned IOPS to standard storage, set this value to 0. The DB instance will require a reboot for the change in storage type to take effect.

[ModifyDBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html)

Comment: But will there be any effect? Like degraded performance? How severe will that be, if any?

Answer (score 26):

So, after @John Hanley's answer (and testing on a test instance) we went ahead with the change.

The Operation took around 1 hour and 6 minutes. Here are the relevant charts from the period.

[image]

We faced no downtime during this period. And even though the total IOPS (~1600) was higher than our old limit (1000) we didn't face any degradation in performance.

Thought this will be helpful for people in the same situation.

Answer (score 6):

In case it saves someone else some delay and worry, we've just done something a lot like this (MySQL 100GB, 1000 IOPS to 2000 IOPS). I'd guess the [Elastic Volumes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-rds-now-supports-database-storage-size-up-to-16tb-and-faster-scaling-for-mysql-mariadb-oracle-and-postgresql-engines/) change is responsible, but we saw only a very small impact on performance for <1min even though we were pretty much maxing out our IOPS with writes before the change. According to RDS Events, the whole modification process took about 2 minutes, though I'm pretty sure the status was "Storage-optimization" for at least half an hour.

Answer (score 3):

We have successfully switched MariaDB GP2 DB with 200GB storage to IOPS 10000, no downtime was noticed.
I can see by the RDS monitoring graphs that connections were dropped, RAM usage was dropped, so apparently it kind of restarted, but it was blazing fast, I can't name it a downtime. [image: metrics]

Answer (score 2):

We're done the same with RDS Postgres 1000GB increasing iops from 3000 to 6000
the modification took less than 10 minutes then Storage-optimization for approx 2 hours.